# How to set date column to date of creation (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

This is a simple question. I want to create a column that stores the date of creation - not the datetime which created_at and created_on do. How do I do this?

**Edit:** I mean the date of the model record. So for example, when a user creates a micropost, I would like to store just the date, and not the datetime.

Comment: Date of creation of what?

Comment: You mean one more column other than `created_at` .

Comment: Created_at is a DateTime column. I need a Date column in addition to the created_at that I can use to validate uniqueness.

Comment: You can create an extra column like `micropost_created_at` with date as its `datatype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavan answered my question in the comment. If you add a column with Date as its datatype, it will automatically set the field to date of creation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional column inside table by creating an extra migration to add that extra column and save the below value while saving the record:

```
Time.now.s­trftime("%­Y-%m-%d")
```

Hope it helps :)